# Convertendo valor TextView para double

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde, no meu projeto estou tendo o seguinte problema.
No mesmo tem uma activity em que é adicionado produtos. Para adicionar um produto é necessário preencher os campos Nome, Quantidade e Valor Unitário.
Os campos quantidade e valor unitário são multiplicados e o resultado é adicionado na coluna `TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM` no meu banco de dados.
Ao fazer a multiplicação dependendo dos valores, está retornando 3 casas decimais

Ex: 1.5 * 1.39 = 2.085 (**2 inteiros e 85 milésimos**)
Sendo que eu quero que retorne apenas 2.08 (**2 inteiros e 8 centésimos**)

Esses valores são resgatados do banco de dados através da função onLoad que se encontra na classe `Controller`

Controller.class (**loadData**)

```
public Cursor loadData() {
    Cursor cursor;

    String[] field = {database.ID, database.PRODUCT_NAME, database.COUNT, database.PRICE_UNIT, database.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM};
    db = database.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query(database.TABLE, field, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

E impresso em uma ListView na minha classe `Main`

```
Controller crud = new Controller(getBaseContext());
final Cursor cursor = crud.loadData();

String[] field = new String[]{CreateDB.ID, CreateDB.PRODUCT_NAME, CreateDB.COUNT, CreateDB.PRICE_UNIT, CreateDB.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM};
int[] idViews = new int[]{R.id.tvId, R.id.tvProductName, R.id.tvCount, R.id.tvPriceUnit, R.id.tvTotalPriceItem};

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
        R.layout.group_layout, cursor, field, idViews, 0);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.elvProductList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

A variável `String[] field` suponho eu que seja responsável por guardar os valores vindo da função `loadData`.
A variável `int[] idViews` suponho que seja responsável por pegar os valores guardados na variável `String[] field` e colocar cada um em seu respectivo lugar.
O valor que está vindo com 3 casas decimais está sendo exibido no `TextView` de id `tvTotalPriceItem`.
Quero saber como converter um valor específico que está em um conjunto de valores.
Não sei se fui muito claro em relação a minha duvida.

Att.
**Giovani Rodrigo**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de limitar a quantidade de casas decimais. Veja abaixo algumas:

[String.format()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

```
double value = 2.085;
String strValue = String.format("%.2f", value );
```

[DecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
double value = 2.085;
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
String strValue = form.format(value);
```

[Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Crie um método usando `.pow` e `.round`:

```
private double limitdecimals(double value, int precision) {
    int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
    return (double) Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
}
```

Use desta forma:
    double value = 2.085;
    String strValue = String.valueOf(limitdecimals(value,2))

[NumberFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

```
double value = 2.085;
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // limita a quantidade de números fracionários
String strValue = format.format(value);
```

Lembrando que as atribuições acima, estão sendo convertidas para `String` para serem impressas no `TextView`. Caso queira fazer alguma operação, você deve mante-las no tipo `double`.

Depois basta você atribuir ao seu `TextView`, usando o método `setText()`. Veja:

```
tvTotalPriceItem.setText(strValue);
```

#### Explorando o SQLite

Uma outra forma legal de fazer isso, seria realizar o procedimento diretamente na *query* através do seu SQLite. Então podes criar uma variável inserindo `printf` para formatar usando o `%.2f`, que reference-se a duas casas decimais. Veja:

```
String valueFormat = "printf('%.2f', "+database.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM+")" +
            " AS "+database.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM;
```

Veja mais detalhes do método `printf()` na [documentação do SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf).

O método `loadData()` ficaria assim:

```
public Cursor loadData() {
    Cursor cursor;
     String valueFormat = "printf('%.2f', "+database.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM+") AS "+database.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM;
    String[] field = {database.ID, database.PRODUCT_NAME, database.COUNT, database.PRICE_UNIT, valueFormat};
    db = database.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query(database.TABLE, field, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Correto, a parte da formatação eu entendi, mas como eu formato um valor que está em um grupo de valores? Como você pode ver o valor a ser formatado está no grupo `String[] field`.

Comment: @GiovaniRodrigo qual variável representa esse conjunto de valores?

Comment: A variável `field`. Suponho que ela seja responsável por comportar todos os valores que serão impressos no `ListView`

Comment: Essa variável está assim na minha class de criação de banco de dados `public static final String TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM = "TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM";`
No SQLite a coluna `TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM` comporta valores `DECIMAL`
Os dados são inseridos nessa coluna no formato double.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, você salvou meu dia!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56461/discussion-between-giovani-rodrigo-and-ack-lay).