# String JSON - Duas casas decimais

Tags: java, android, json

Estou lendo um objeto JSON, e consigo obter os dados nos `TextView`. 
Porém, no valor da `String Preco` quando o preço possui um zero na segunda casa decimal, ele não imprime no `TextView`. 
Por exemplo: `9.20` exibe `9.2`. Tentei algumas funções, porém, sem sucesso. 
Alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] jsonWinthor) {
        txtCodProd.setText(jsonWinthor[0]);
        txtDescProduto.setText(jsonWinthor[1]);
        txtValor.setText(jsonWinthor[2]);
        txtSifrao.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Objeto JSON lido:

```
{"Codigo":78,"Descricao":"BANDEJA PINT.TIGRE 1308","Preco":9.20,"CodigoBarra":"78"}
```

Comment: Jovem, por favor, poste seu código em texto e não em imagem.

Comment: Ok. Feito alteração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode primeiro converter para `double` e para usar o format. Veja:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(jsonWinthor[2]);
String strValue = String.format("%.2f", value );
```

Veja [nessa respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194549/35406) outras maneiras de como fazer isso.

Comment: Valeu ! Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado ! Abç.